# react-native-udp - bound port not same as what my server is seeing

Tags: python, sockets, react-native, udp

On the React-Native side, I'm binding to port 55555.

```
import dgram from 'react-native-udp';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

const foo = ()=>{
    var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
    socket.bind(55555, '0.0.0.0', (e)=>{
        if(e) console.log(e)
    })
    socket.once('listening', function() {
        var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify('msg'))
        socket.send(buf, 0, buf.length, 5000, MACHINE_LOCAL_IP, function(err) {
            if (err) alert(err)
            console.log('Sent to', MACHINE_LOCAL_IP)
        })
    })
}
```

I'm seeing the following console log

```
socket-0 bound to address: 0.0.0.0 port: 55555
Sent to [...]
```

It works as expected maybe 8 / 10 times. On my server side, I'm opening a UDP socket in python

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(1)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
while True:
    try:
        data, in_address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(in_address)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

When I run `foo` multiple times, here's my python output

```
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 55555) 
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 52917)
('192.168.0.5', 49619)
('192.168.0.5', 63532)
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
('192.168.0.5', 55555)
```

I'm not able to figure out why the port is changing!